# mongoengine cannot use collection in response

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, swagger, mongoengine

[EDITED]

I have any api using flask + connexion (swagger 2.0)

Any time I retrieve a collection from the database, using simple code such as:

```
# GET /api/model
def get_all_model():
    return Model.objects
```

I get the following error:

> TypeError: [Model] is not JSON serializable

As a workaround, I have done the following

```
def get_all_model():
    return json.loads(model.objects.to_json())
```

**How can I return the entire collection without serializing/deserializing?**

from the docs:

> Document classes have an objects attribute, which is used for
>   accessing the objects in the database associated with the class. **The
>   objects attribute is actually a QuerySetManager**, which creates and
>   returns a new QuerySet object on access. The QuerySet object may be
>   iterated over to fetch documents from the database:

Answer (score 1):

The question is clear now. I think there is no way to return a list instead of queryset to serialize it directly to JSON. Though, you should do it yourself by iterating over all documents (using queryset object) and putting them in a list of dictionaries. I recommend doing something like this:

```
import mongoengine

mongoengine.connect('mongoenginetest', host='mongomock://localhost')

class Student(mongoengine.Document):
    name = mongoengine.StringField()

    @mongoengine.queryset_manager
    def serialized_objects(doc_cls, queryset):
        return [{'name': doc.name} for doc in queryset]

student1 = Student(name='John')
student1.save()

print(type(Student.serialized_objects))  # prints <class 'list'>
print(Student.serialized_objects)  # prints [{'name': 'John'}]
```

You can rename serialized_objects to objects. Also, look at this page:https://gist.github.com/benwah/3009143

Happy day!

Comment: I've edited the question to be more clear. I am trying to avoid having to serialize and then deserialize because it is unnecessary work being done. There should be a way to get the items as a python dictionary? I thought `as_pymongo()` would do this, but it does not appear to be the case